# How to change jdk path in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, jdk, openjdk

I have downloaded the jdk 91 update from the oracle.com
I want to apply this update. I kept the `.tar.gz` file in the directory having `path /home/amrit/jdk8/`.
I tarball and extracted the file.

Now when I did `javac -version` it still showed me openjdk-7 as the version.
I think the jdk path needs to be changed. How can I do that?